# Understanding the "where" and how to use it in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, where-clause, helper

I have a table named `product_variations`, and this table has_many `products`.

When I go to Rails console, I can do this:

```
2.6.3 :036 > var = ProductVariation.first
  ProductVariation Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `product_variations`.* FROM `product_variations` ORDER BY `product_variations`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
 => #<ProductVariation id: 16, product_id: 1024, color_id: 19, quantity: 1, size: "GG", sub_sku: 10, created_at: "2020-02-18 14:41:46", updated_at: "2020-02-18 14:41:46">
2.6.3 :037 > var.size
 => "GG"
```

So, that's working. But when I try to find something there using `where`, I got this intead:

```
2.6.3 :038 > var = ProductVariation.where(product_id: 1024, sub_sku: 10)
  ProductVariation Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `product_variations`.* FROM `product_variations` WHERE `product_variations`.`product_id` = 1024 AND `product_variations`.`sub_sku` = 10 LIMIT 11
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<ProductVariation id: 16, product_id: 1024, color_id: 19, quantity: 1, size: "GG", sub_sku: 10, created_at: "2020-02-18 14:41:46", updated_at: "2020-02-18 14:41:46">]>
2.6.3 :039 > var.size
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `product_variations` WHERE `product_variations`.`product_id` = 1024 AND `product_variations`.`sub_sku` = 10
 => 1
```

Note that when I try to use `var.size`, the console do another search at the database, but now using `SELECT COUNT(*)` instead of just `SELECT`, and the output is `1` (while should be `GG`, why?). For what I understood until now, `where` can return many results. Thats why it uses `COUNT`? But how can I use the result? In this app I'm working at, on the `product_variations` table I'll have only one single match with `product_id` and `sub_sku` so I want it to return this line, but can't figure out how to use `where` to do this.

Comment: I see you got your answer below.  When you call `where` it returns a relation which you can chain calls onto, `ProductVariation.where(product_id: 1024).offset(10).limit(10).where(sub_sku: 10).where.not(size: nil)`.  If you chain `size` or `count` it will make the query into a `count` query.  In dbugger's answer, `first` or `find_by` ends the chain and returns a record object.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed informattion, @MarlinPierce. I tried to search on the web more info about the ```where``` and I only got very simple examples... was struggling to understand that. Now I see what the ```ActiveRecord::Relation``` means on the console's return and how to use it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use .first after the where

```
var = ProductVariation.where(product_id: 1024, sub_sku: 10).first
```

or use the find_by method

```
var = ProductVariation.find_by(product_id: 1024, sub_sku: 10)
```

which will do the same thing